# mgcv: Error Model has more coefficients than data, related to the argument by in the gam()

Tags: r, spline, mgcv

In case a, the gam code in mgcv R package is working well.

```r
library(mgcv)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)

num_knots = nrow(dat)
fit <- gam(y~s(x0, bs = "cr", k = num_knots, m=2),data=dat)
summary(fit)
```

But after I added the argument by in the gam(), it reported the error "Model has more coefficients than data".

```r
fit <- gam(y~s(x0, bs = "cr", k = num_knots, m=2, by = x1),data=dat)
```

The error confuses me because I thought adding the by argument to create the interaction between the smoothing term and the parametric term should not increase the number of unknown coefficients, though it turns out that I am wrong. Where was I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a continuous variable to `by`, what you are getting is varying coefficient model where the effect of `x1` varies as a smooth function of `x0`.

What is happening in the first case is that because of identifiability constraints being applied to the basis expansion for `x0`, you requested `num_knots` basis functions but actually got `num_knots - 1` basis functions. When you add the intercept you get `num_knots` coefficients which is OK to fit with this model as it is a penalised spline (though you probably want `method = 'REML'`). The identifiability constraint is applied because there is a basis function (or combination) that is confounded with the model intercept and you can't fit two constant terms in the model and have them be uniquely identified.

In the second case, the varying coefficient model, there isn't the same issue, so when you ask for `num_knots` basis functions plus an intercept you are trying to fit a model with 401 coefficients with 400 observations which isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I may ask a follow-up question for the second case. Does that mean in the varying coefficient model, the regression splines are not penalized? Is that the reason that there are 401 parameter coefficients to estimate?

Comment: In the second case there were 401 parameters and mgcv just won't do that; it's not like the Lasso-type penalisation where can p>n. In the first case there were 400 parameters, ~398 of which were penalised (there is a term that isn't penalised in the basis which is why you can't shrink a term out of the model entirely, just to a linear function). If you set `k = num_knots - 1` your second case would be estimated & it would be a penalised regression spline. You only get a non-penalised spline if you set `fx = TRUE` in all `s()` (or `te()`, etc) terms.

Comment: There are 401 parameters in your second case because you have an intercept and you asked for a basis expansion of 400 basis functions and got all 400 functions you asked for. In the first case you asked for a basis expansion of 400 basis functions but identifiability constraints meant that you only got 399 basis functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dr. Simpson. To clarify the statement 'it's not like the Lasso-type penalization where can p>n', my understanding is that in the penalized regression splines, it penalizes the curvature via the second order derivatives. This penalizing does not have the ability to reduce the number of unknown coefficients. Is this correct?

Comment: I just found another useful website, https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/teaching/ , to the package mgcv for my further reading.

Comment: Re penalised splines, yes, that's right; we shrink the estimated coefficients for each basis function, based on the (default) penalty of some amount of the integrated squared second derivative of the spline, but you can't have a model with more coefficients than data. Welcome to my website too ;-)